# How to create a query using Criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have a class called Vote:

```
@Table(name = "PHY_VOTE")
public class VoteEntity extends BaseEntity<Long> implements Comparable {

    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    public static final String VALUE = "value";
    public static final String USER = "user";

    private String title;
    private String value;

    private UserEntity user;

    public VoteEntity() {}

    public VoteEntity(Long id) {
        setId(id);
    }

    public VoteEntity(String title, String value, UserEntity user) {
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "VOTE_ID")
    @Override
    public Long getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @FilterProperty(operation = FilterProperty.ILIKE)
    @Column(name = "TITLE", nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @FilterProperty(operation = FilterProperty.ILIKE)
    @Column(name = "VALUE", nullable = false, length = 4)
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "PYH_VOTE_USER_FK"))
    public UserEntity getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(UserEntity user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Transient
    @Override
    public String getOptionsTitleProperty() {
        return TITLE;
    }

}
```

How can I create the following command with Criteria?

SELECT  t.TITLE , ROUND(SUM(t.VALUE) / COUNT(t.TITLE) , 2) value FROM PHY_VOTE  t GROUP BY t.TITLE

Comment: Google helps a lot here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection. You might need to do the rounding in code, as I'm not sure that Criteria supports that out of the box (so select both the `sum` and the `count`.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider doing it with [FluentJPA](https://github.com/streamx-co/FluentJPA):

```java
public AverageByTitle getAverageByTitle() {
    FluentQuery query = FluentJPA.SQL((VoteEntity t) -> {

        Alias<Number> avg = alias(ROUND(SUM(INT.raw(t.getValue())) / COUNT(t.getTitle()), 2),
                AverageByTitle::getAverage);

        SELECT(t.getTitle(), avg);
        FROM(t);
        GROUP(BY(t.getTitle()));
    });

    return query.createQuery(em, AverageByTitle.class).getSingleResult();
}

// declarations

public static final DataType<Integer> INT = DataTypes.INT;

@Tuple
@Data // lombok
public static class AverageByTitle {
    private String title;
    private float average;
}
```

which produces the following SQL:

```
SELECT t0.TITLE, ROUND((SUM(t0.VALUE) / COUNT(t0.TITLE)), 2) AS average
FROM PHY_VOTE t0
GROUP BY  t0.TITLE
```